# How to encode html code or url to this format \u00253Cbr\....?

Tags: javascript, html

How to encode html code or url to this format?:

```
\u00253Cb\u002522\....
```

THANK YOU!

Comment: In order to know which enconding are you talking you should provide the original string that match `\u00253Cb\u002522`.  Chekc this tool too: https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter

Answer (score 1):

To convert URL to this you need to convert  your URL (string) to unicode format

you can try following function for it.

```
// here toUnicode function is attached to string so that it can used further with 
//other strings also

String.prototype.toUnicode = function(){
    var result = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
        // Assumption: all characters are < 0xffff
        result += "\\u" + ("000" + this[i].charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).substr(-4);
    }
    return result;
};

let name = "john";

name.toUnicode(); // this will return unicodes of strings
```

And on another side you can get the Unicode URL using `window.location.href`  (which will be in unicode) you can convert back into string using following function.

```
// this function coverts the unicode to string char by char 
// so you need to loop through the string and call this function a
//nd create resultant string

function unicodeToChar(text) {
   return text.replace(/\\u[\dA-F]{4}/gi, 
          function (match) {
               return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(match.replace(/\\u/g, ''), 16));
          });
}
```